# Ending up outside of a review queue when editing a post twice

Tags: discussion, bug, review, suggested-edits

In case it's important: I'm a low rep user and can only make suggested edits. This way I can reproduce the problem:

- I enter a review queue and find a post that I want to improve.
- I hit the <kbd>edit</kbd> button below the post to enter the edit mode.
- After editing, I hit the <kbd>Save Edits</kbd> button. This brings me back to the post in the review queue (as expected).
- Immediately afterwards I notice that I missed to fix something on the post.
- I hit the <kbd>edit</kbd> button once again to enter the edit mode a second time.
- After improving my previous edit, I hit the <kbd>Save Edits</kbd> button again. This time, I get back to the post, but *outside* of the review queue (not as expected).

After these steps I can still go back to the post in the review queue by pressing the *Back* button of my browser twice.
Then I can even hit the <kbd>I'm Done</kbd> button to complete my review.

Does this "work as designed"? If yes, I find it very annoying: Even after editing a post twice, I'd like to stay in the review queue. Or am I doing something wrong here?

**Edit:** This bug report is now around here for about two weeks. The comments indicate that my issue could be reproduced by other users. I know it's not the biggest deal and I don't expect any answer, but shouldn't this post get tagged with either [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned), [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred), or at least [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)?